# Equivalence of Shortest Hamiltonian Paths with a Starting Node to Traveling Salesman Problem

Tags: traveling-salesman, hamiltonian-path

[image]

Q- Can someone explain  the equivalence in detail please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correspondence is almost the same as your [other question](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/5542/equivalence-of-shortest-hamiltonian-paths-to-traveling-salesman-problem).  Here, the starting node is specified, so you don't need a dummy node or dummy arcs out of the starting node.  To go from H-path (with start $1$ and end $t$) to tour, insert arc $(t,1)$. To go from tour to H-path, remove the arc that enters $1$.